# Local port is not accessible with public IP address

Tags: linux, iptables, ip, nginx, port-forwarding

I have a linux server which has public IP and Private IP. So, when ever I login with public IP, the terminal directly shows private IP.

example:

```
$ ssh root@55.27.XX.XX
root's password: 
root@10.1.4.20:~$ hostname -I
10.1.4.20
root@10.1.4.20:~$ wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain ; echo
55.27.xx.xx
```

Now, I installed Nginx and I am able to load 55.27.xx.xx with default nginx page. But, when I installed phpmyadmin with port 85, It is not allowing me to access the page from public IP.

If I use `curl 10.1.4.20:85`, I get `200 OK response`. But curl `55.27.xx.xx:85`, I get timeout.

Same with netcat command:

```
root@10.1.4.20:~$ nc -vz localhost 85
nc: connect to localhost port 85 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
Connection to localhost 85 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
root@10.1.4.20:~$ nc -vz 55.27.xx.xx 85
nc: connectx to 55.27.xx.xx port 85 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out
```

Probably the server might be behind some router:

```
root@10.1.4.20:~$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:55:00:tt:a6:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.4.20/16 brd 10.4.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 dddd::xxxx:ff:4534/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I did not do any port forwarding steps. I see `iptables -L` with blank output as below:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

From the server, I cannot ping google.com

```
ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2000ms
```

Please suggest what needs to be done to access phpmyadmin with port 85 from public IP address.

Comment: Is your server behind a router, or is it directly connected to the Internet? Have you forwarded port tcp/85 to your server? If you're not sure you can provide the output of `ip addr show`. Please [update your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/220106/edit) to include this information rather than reply in the comments, so that it doesn't get lost.

Comment: Thank you. I updated with all the details. Can you please help me out!

Answer (score 3):

The entry for `ip addr show` demonstrates that your server has only a local address:

```
inet 10.1.4.20/16 brd 10.4.255.255 scope global eth0
```

You need to review your external NAT device that maps your `55.27.XX.XX` address to `10.1.4.20` and provide port forwarding for port tcp/85.

Comment: I added one more ip by `sudo ip addr add xxx.yyyy.wwww.zzz dev eth0`

Comment: @vladkras unless you are also Kasino that sounds like a [new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: no, it's a clue rather than a question

Comment: @vladkras you've lost me completely. A clue to what?